# Cisco 7945 Phone won't boot after power outage

Tags: cisco, phone

I have two Cisco 7945 phones that will not boot after a recent power outage.  I tried using this (http://amyengineer.com/tag/9-31sr1/) method to load the firmware back on.  Sadly, the phone doesn't even get an IP address.  The the screen light up, but it doesn't stay on.  Only the green speaker button stays on.

Are these phones completely shot?

Comment: Sounds like a great question for Cisco support.

Comment: This should be directed to Cisco support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are these phones completely shot?

Sure sounds like it.  I would ask Cisco support and/or try to get a warranty repair.  Probably best not to mention that they may or may not have gotten fried by bad power input.

But beyond that, broken hardware is only marginally useful for holding open doors and keeping papers from blowing away, so if you want phones that work, you'll need to procure working phones.

Comment: Sadly, the phones are out of warranty.

Comment: @KentAllard Well, then you have bricks.  If you have additional, in-warranty phones of the same model, you can often get support to diagnose and/or verify that your hardware's toast, provided you're not above a little lying or deception when you call in.  You're pretty short on options, though, and it looks like it's time for replacements.